# How to deploy examples given in Sencha touch folder to tablets and phone

Tags: sencha-touch-2.1

I want to deploy kitchensink application to android phone and tablet using cordova.
But when I open kitchensink folder, I do not see any build folder there. So I am not able to build the project. So please tell me a way out to deploy these sencha applications to phone and tablets.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [Sencha CMD](http://www.sencha.com/products/sencha-cmd/download) to build the app.

With this tool you can build Android Apps directly using the built in ["native packaging" funcationality](http://docs.sencha.com/cmd/4.0.0/#!/guide/native_packaging) or cordova / phonegap.

**Built-in native packaging:**

1. Create packager.json (see [native packaging help page](http://docs.sencha.com/cmd/4.0.0/#!/guide/native_packaging) for config parameters)

   sencha app package generate packager.json
2. Build the app

   sencha app build native

**Build using cordova**

1. Prepare your sencha project for a cordova build

   sencha cordova init AppId AppName
2. Build the app

   sencha app build native

For more information, checkout the [sencha cmd guide](http://docs.sencha.com/cmd/4.0.0/#!/guide) or the [sencha cordova/phonegap build tutorial video](http://vimeo.com/76568053).